# Angular 6 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: angular

I know this question has been already asked but I couldn't find any suitable solution.

I'm trying to make a `post` request. The API needs a `x-www-form-urlencoded` body format so I ended up doing like so:

```
login(account: LogAccount): Observable<any> {
 const body = new HttpParams()
  .set('username', account.username)
  .set('password', account.password);

  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
  return this.http.post(`${environment.api.apiUrl}/loginservice`, body.toString(),
{ headers });
```

}

Which leads to :

[image]

Everything works fine using Postman.
What am I missing here?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show what is actually passed in `body.toString()`?

Comment: Doing a `console.log(body.toString())` will give me `username=helen.kelly&password=bpm`

Comment: you are passing same in postman? I think it should be json like `{"username":"helen.kelly", "password":"bpm"}`

Comment: The API is expecting x-www-form-urlencoded, not a JSON

Comment: Your `error.text` will give you way more information. Can you share that? One thing that's wrong is the `body.toString()`, you should not parse it to string

Comment: The `error.text` gives a HTML page. I've got the all <doctype...> thing.

Comment: @GreatHawkeye I understand that, but there is probably an error being printed in that HTML page. And that will probably be your answer to what's wrong

Comment: @PierreDuc, here it is : https://pastebin.com/aWfKCK2M
I believe, though, that it is expecting JSON instead of HTML.

Comment: @GreatHawkeye so no error there :D have you tried remove the `.toString()` on the body?

Comment: @PierreDuc, yep and I got the same result. Everything is working on postman, I'm getting a 200 status with the correct credentials and 401 with incorrect ones.