# ionic : api prints response in html format and gives error ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: api, post, ionic3, httprequest

I'm trying to call API for login page, when i run API in postman it give response in JSON format but the problem is when i call API through ionic app it gives response in HTML Code and gives error . I don't understand where is the problem. please help me

.html code

```
 <ion-item style="margin-top:40px;">
        <ion-label style="color:#BBBBBD; font-size:12px;" floating>USERNAME </ion-label>
        <ion-input style="margin-top:20px;font-size:15px;" [(ngModel)]="users.email" name="email" type="email"></ion-input>
        <hr style="margin-top:-5px">
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item style="margin-top:16px;">
        <ion-label style="color:#BBBBBD; font-size:12px;" floating>PASSWORD </ion-label>
        <ion-input style="margin-top:20px;font-size:15px;" [(ngModel)]="users.password" name="password" type="password"></ion-input>
        <hr style="margin-top:-5px">
    </ion-item>

    <div (click)="forgotPassword()">
        <ion-label style="color:#BBBBBD; display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;text-align:center;font-size:13px;margin-bottom: 60px;"
            floating>FORGOT PASSWORD</ion-label>
    </div>
    <button class="login-btn" ion-button round (click)="doLogin()">Login</button>
```

auth-services.ts

```
login(credentials) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  let headers = new Headers(
    {
      'content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
  this.http.post(LOGIN, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers}).
  subscribe(res =>{
    console.log("json data",res.json.toString);
    resolve(res.json());
  }, (err) =>{
    reject(err);
  });

});
```

}

login.ts

```
resposeData: any;
users = { "email": "", "password": "" };
public doLogin() {
if (this.users.email && this.users.password) {
  this.authService.login(this.users).then((result) => {
    this.resposeData = result;
    console.log(this.resposeData);
    if (this.resposeData.userData) {
      localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.resposeData))
      this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
    }
    else {
      this.presentToast("Please enter valid username and password");
    }
  }, (err) => {
    //Connection failed message
  });
}
else {
  this.presentToast("Please enter username and password");
}
```

}

in postman it shows correct response:

```
 {
"success": {
    "email": "admin@example.com",
    "password": "admin",
    "status": 1
} }
```

but when i try to get from app it shows html code

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222400/angular-6-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-at-json-parse

Comment: Why don't you just return the post response from auth-service.ts and subscribe the service on login.ts? That way you wouldn't need to resolve the promise.